# How to make part of tooltip hide in a grid,it seems my codes does not work

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to make part of tooltip hide ,it seems my codes does not work
Here is my codes:

```
$("#Grid").kendoTooltip({
                filter: "td",
                content: function (e) {
                    var container = e.target;
                    if (container.find(".tooltipcontent").html() == undefined ) {
                       container.tooltip( "hide");
                    }

                    return container.find(".tooltipcontent").html();
                }


            }).data("kendoTooltip");
        }
```

It say that `container.tooltip( "hide")` is error.I just want to show the tooltip on cell only the cell has 'tooltipcontent' class

Comment: What is the error..??

Comment: container has no function called toolip("hide")

Comment: container is an element such method won't be there, which is the reason why is it not working. And I don't understand what are you doing there anyway ? Class .tooltipcontent is I am guessing some other then kendo tooltip so you are trying move the content of one tooltip to an other, please explain ??

Comment: container(means td) has a div which class name called 'tooltipcontent ',the div is here:<div class='tooltipcontent' style='display:none;'>text</div>

Comment: I'm afraid that the problem is that inside `content` handler the tooltip is still not displayed so you are actually not hiding it. Try setting an `alarm("hi");` in `content` handler function and you will see that the tooltip is not displayed until you close the `alarm` window. So you should try to set the class only for those columns that you want to show the tooltip. If you show in JSFiddle/JSBin an example of how you are defining the cells I can try to suggest you how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with

```
container.tooltip();
```

Simply Try to disable the tooltip like

```
container.tooltip('disable');
```

Comment: It still has a toolip window and show nothing,but I want to hide the tooltip window!

Comment: Thanks  Gautam3164 ,now the container(cell) still show the whole tooltip window which is belongs to its'  adjacent cell

Comment: still not,I want to  hide the tooltip,but now it show its' neighbors tooltip because it is disalbe,I think it will be ok if make its tooltip hide,How to do that?

Comment: That means you want to hide all the tooltip,for #Grid also..??

Comment: only hide the tooltip that container has no class called 'tooltipcontent', the tooltip's contain is in a div which class name is called 'tooltipcontent'

Comment: Please refrain from asking people to vote/accept your answers. [See this meta post for more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167155/152134). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change this :

```
if (container.find(".tooltipcontent").html() == undefined ) {
  container.tooltip( "hide");
}
```

to this:

```
if (container.is(".tooltipcontent")) {
  container.tooltip();
}
```

This will check if the target is `.tooltipcontent` if true then assing the tooltip method to it.

Comment: It still has a toolip window and show nothing,but I want to hide the tooltip window!

Answer (score 0):

Ok Now I get what you after :

....I just want to show the tooltip on cell only the cell has 'tooltipcontent' class.

1) call the kendotooltip only on your classes, not on the parent grid
2) e.target will give you access to the control you using the tooltip on

```
$(".tooltipcontent").kendoTooltip({
               filter: "td",                
               content: function (e) {
                         console.log(e.target.html());
                         return e.target.html();
                      },              
               }).data("kendoTooltip");
             }
```

Comment: call the kendotooltip only on your classes, not on the parent grid.It is really too slow,I want to tooltip all the td,and at last make some td which has no 'tooltipcontain' hide,but I do not how to make them hide